# Xamarin Android: System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory Fails in release mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Everything works fine in debug mode but when we run it in release the ExtractToDirectory call fails.

Here is the function for reference. Just to make sure we are not doing anything weird.

```
private bool UnzipFiles()
    {
        bool toReturn = true;
        try
        {
            UpdateStatus("Almost done...");
            string file = Path.Combine (DownloadFolder, "ZipFile.zip");
            if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(UnzippingDestinationFolder))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(UnzippingDestinationFolder, recursive:true);
            }

            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, UnzippingDestinationFolder);
            UpdateStatus("Finished!");
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(UnzippingDestinationFolder);

            int m = 3;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            toReturn = false;
        }
```

Finally, here is the exception we get.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at SharpCompress.Common.Zip.Headers.ZipFileEntry.DecodeString (System.Byte[] str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SharpCompress.Common.Zip.Headers.DirectoryEntryHeader.Read (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SharpCompress.Common.Zip.ZipHeaderFactory.ReadHeader (UInt32 headerBytes, System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SharpCompress.Common.Zip.SeekableZipHeaderFactory+<ReadSeekableHeader>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SharpCompress.Archive.Zip.ZipArchive+<LoadEntries>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SharpCompress.LazyReadOnlyCollection`1+LazyLoader[SharpCompress.Archive.Zip.ZipArchiveEntry].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.CreateZip (System.IO.Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open (System.String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory (System.String sourceArchiveFileName, System.String destinationDirectoryName, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory (System.String sourceArchiveFileName, System.String destinationDirectoryName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NewBaron.Screens.DownloadContentScreen.UnzipFiles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: A few things to try:
- That library is open source, put the source code into your project and debug it. The null reference will be pretty obvious when it occurs.
- Include all the character sets into the apk. [Project Options] -> Android Build -> Linker -> Internationalization.

Comment: Also, disable the linker in Release mode.

Answer (score 5):

A slight changes to Victor's solution. Not linking the SDKs generated an apk that was 53MBs. Too large for the play store's apk size limit.

I set the linking behavior to link SDK assemblies only and it brought the apk size down to 29MBs

Here is the updated window.

[image]

Comment: Much better answer. Also this this solution helped fix the same issue on a Xamarin.Mac app.

Comment: This solved my problem, maintaining the .apk file small due to only SDK assemblies only.

Answer (score 1):

@mattewrobbinsdev's suggestion was exactly it. For future readers, here's the dialog in Xamarin Studio:

[image: Dialog]

Comment: It'd be useful to determine *why* this fixes it... My best guess is that the linker is stripping out an API that SharpCompress uses via reflection. If you want to fix this without disabling the linker, identify the class that is being removed and make a stub usage of it. The standard is to make a `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/nuspec/DroidContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.pp

Comment: The option link behaviour: don't link, worket for me.
The System.IO.Compression was crashing when unziping a file in RELEASE mode. The problem is that the .APK file duplicate it size. 
In my case the .APK was 25mb and after the don't link it was 50bm.

Comment: Did anyone ever log a bug in Xamarin's bugzilla?

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to this Bugzilla bug. Notice Comment #5 about including the I10N stuff: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36154#c5   This was originally linked from here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36318